# How to add border to code blocks in generated beamer pdf from Markdown using Pandoc

Tags: border, markdown, pandoc, beamer

I've found how to add line numbers by writing,

````
```{.c .numberLines}
int x = 1;
int y = x;
```
````

But wonder how to add a border to the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way to do this is to modify the `default.beamer` template and pass the `--listings` variable to pandoc during pdf creation. Take a look at the information for frames in the listings documentation: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf